# 「させていただく」or「させてくださる」

Tags: keigo

> **その俳優が大好きなので、ぜひ私に彼へのインタビューを（　　）。**
>
> A.させてくださいませんか　B.させていただけませんか

Here is my understanding of these two options (which can be wrong):

A: "you" is the subject, will "you" not give "me" the permission to "do something"?

B: "I" is the subject, can "I" have the permission from "you" to "do something"?

Which one, A or B, is correct or better for this situation?

Answer (score 1):

The difference between させてくださいませんか and させていただけませんか would be the point of view

In させてくださいませんか => someone gives you something (you are not the subjet in the sentence)

させていただけませんか => you receive something from someone (you are the subject in the sentence)

Here you have 私に in your sentence so I think the answer would be A : させてくださいませんか

Comment: When asking for help, which would be better? 〜てくれませんか or 〜てもらえませんか